# EXCEL; I would like to match two email address from two different worksheets and return a value of 2 cells (phone numbers)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, cross-reference

i have two work sheets one contains ALL the information and one is a filtered version with some additional info add, i would like to match an email addresses (column Q)sheet 1 to (column D) sheet 2 and return the value of column O and P from sheet 1 to column H and I on sheet 2

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hey @Adam,, please [edit] your post and add some sample data you are trying to match with ,,, the the expected output,, along with formula you have tried so far,,!

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your sheet1 looks like this
[sheet1 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvLbP.png)

And your sheet2 looks like this:
[sheet2 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38efz.png)

I'm going to suggest the function VLOOKUP for this. You need to understand, that the column you are looking up should always be the left of the data you need.

So you see in the sheet1 pic, that the email address is in Column Q but the data you want to put in the sheet2 are in Columns O and P

The first thing we need to do is move the email address in Sheet1 to Column N so its left of Columns O and P so you can look up the values from Sheet2. See the following image:

[Shee1 Email in Col N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17M2j.png)

Then you can go to sheet2 and in Columns H and I you can use the Vlookup function. See image
[vlookup function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFavK.png)

Then you can easily drag down and you'll have everything filled like this:
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXB5p.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these formulae on Sheet2. Assuming In H2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!O$2:O$3,MATCH($D2,Sheet6!$Q$2:$Q$3,0))
```

In I2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!P$2:P$3,MATCH($D2,Sheet6!$Q$2:$Q$3,0))
```

Adapt the ranges on both formulae.